# How to append text to beginning and end of each item in a list?

Tags: string, python-3.6

I've looked everywhere for a way to do this but to no avail. What I have is a list, lets say I have this list:

```
['T','E','S','T']
```

I want to find a way to append ":regional_indicator_" to the beginning and ":" to the end of each item on the list, with the original list characters inbetween, so the end result is:

```
[':regional_indicator_T:',':regional_indicator_E:',':regional_indicator_S:','regional_indicator_T']
```

Comment: What did you try? Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the list one element at a time using range (In this case, `len(li)` returns `4` so `range(4)` will go 0-1-2-3, which are the indices of your list).

```
li = ['T','E','S','T']
for _ in range(len(li)):
  li[_] = ":regional_indicator_" + li[_] + ":"
print(li)
```

As you can see, we can concatenate the strings using the `+` operator.

To ignore empty entries (spaces) in the list, you can add in a check:

```
li = ['T','E','S','T']
for _ in range(len(li)):
    if ( len(li[_]) > 0 ) and ( li[_] != " " ): 
        li[_] = ":regional_indicator_" + li[_] + ":"
print(li)
```

See more on [Iterating over a list using for loops](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/for_loops.html) and [String Concatenation](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

Comment: I've run into another problem, it adds :regional_indicator_ : to characters that aren't letters as well, which causes a problem. Can I also use a loop to look through the list to detect a space and if it does it won't add :regional_indicator_ :? and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: That is very simple, you just throw in a check before you modify the position in the list, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I forgot that I needed to add a space after each item, so I've added 

    `for _ in range(len(a)):
    if ( len(a[_]) > 0 ) and ( a[_] != " " ): 
        a[_] = ":regional_indicator_" + a[_] + ":" + a[_] + " "` but It just adds the original character in the item instead of a space, sorry for all the problems!

Comment: `a[_]` is your original character; that is the value of `a` at position `_` where `_` is 0, then 1, 2, and 3. What you want is to add a space, so make that third part: `":regional_indicator_" + a[_] + ": "` Note the space is in the same string as the colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) and apply a lambda that will do the concatenation for you:

```
map(lambda x: ':regional_indicator_{}:'.format(x), ['T', 'E', 'S', 'T'])
```

And whatever you can do with map, you can also do with list comprehension:

```
 [':regional_indicator_{}:'.format(x) for x in ['T', 'E', 'S', 'T']]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[':regional_indicator_T:', ':regional_indicator_E:', ':regional_indicator_S:', ':regional_indicator_T:']
```